# Getting layers to show up again to left of ArcMap

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, table-of-contents

The list (Table of Contents) with all my layers disappeared in ArcMap.

How can I get the list back again?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

A quick google search turned up this:

Procedure
If the Table of Contents disappears from view, follow these steps to reactivate it.

1.Click Windows on the Main menu.

2.Click Table of Contents.

http://support.esri.com/es/knowledgebase/techarticles/detail/35322